# Deleting data from Access with VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2000

I'm trying to delete every record from my current Access database in VBA where `OTP = txtOTP.value` and `VARIABLE = {NomAdminContrats,TelAdminContrats,TelecAdminContrats, [...]}`

Here is my code:

```vb
Dim query As Recordset 
Set query = CurrentDb.Execute("DELETE * FROM tb_SOMMAIRE WHERE OTP = '" & txtOTP.value & "' AND (VARIABLE = 'NomAdminContrats' or VARIABLE = 'TitreAdminContrats' or VARIABLE = 'UnitAdminContrats' or VARIABLE = 'AdrAdminContrats' or  VARIABLE = 'VilleAdminContrats' or VARIABLE = 'TelAdminContrats' or VARIABLE = 'TelecAdminContrats' or VARIABLE = 'CourrielAdminContrats')")
```

I got an error 3219 Invalid Operation when trying with OpenRecordset or *Expected function* when trying with Execute. I've tried a lot of things but I didn't manage yet to get this query working. I also have the full table in a recordset, would it be easier/faster to do it with myRecordset.Delete? If so, how could I do it?

**EDIT**

Now trying with CurrentDb.Execute instead of CurrentDb.OpenRecordset. The error is now *Function expected* instead of *Invalid Operation*.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `CurrentDb.Execute`, for a `DELETE` statement?...

Comment: It doesn't work either, with the parenthesis (`CurrentDb.Execute()`) I get an error "Function expected" and without the parenthesis I get a syntax error.

Comment: Finally managed to get it working, thank you. I will post the final code below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were not supposed to use parentheses for the `recordset.execute` function, unless you want to send the `execute` function *options*, as well as your query.

```
currentDB.Execute ("SQL EXECUTABLE QUERY", Options)
```

*options* is an optional constant that you can include in the function, such as **dbDenyWrite**, or **dbFailOnError**. when you don't include *options* in your execute function, Microsoft uses the default **dbInconsistent**, and you should not use parentheses.

```
Set query = CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * FROM tb_SOMMAIRE..."
```

The reason your code worked when you used the variable `sql` is because you did not use the parantheses when you used the variable.

Comment: Since this answer is more accurate than my workaround, I will set this as the accepted answer. However, at this point, the title is a little bit misleading since it's a not a problem with a specific function in VBA but more of a syntax problem on my part. Anyone can feel free to edit. Thank you, even though it's more than 3 years old lol.

Answer (score 3):

You already solved the problem.  Congratulations.  See whether a different approach for your `WHERE` clause is easier to work with.

The `WHERE` clause checks whether `VARIABLE` matches a list of values.  Instead of using multiple `OR` conditions to compare `VARIABLE` with each member of the list, you can simply ask the db engine whether `VARIABLE` is present `IN` the list of values.

```
AND
    (
        [VARIABLE] IN
            (
                'NomAdminContrats',
                'TitreAdminContrats',
                'UnitAdminContrats',
                'AdrAdminContrats',
                'VilleAdminContrats',
                'TelAdminContrats',
                'TelecAdminContrats',
                'CourrielAdminContrats'
            )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to get it working. Had to declare another var for the query for some reason.

```vb
Dim sql as String
sql = "DELETE * FROM tb_SOMMAIRE WHERE OTP = '" & txtOTP.value & "' AND (VARIABLE = 'NomAdminContrats' or VARIABLE = 'TitreAdminContrats' or VARIABLE = 'UnitAdminContrats' or VARIABLE = 'AdrAdminContrats' or  VARIABLE = 'VilleAdminContrats' or VARIABLE = 'TelAdminContrats' or VARIABLE = 'TelecAdminContrats' or VARIABLE = 'CourrielAdminContrats')"
CurrentDb.Execute sql
```